# Regular expression for a substring from a line

Tags: c#, regex

I have a line XX,VV,A01,A02,A03,A11,A12,A13,A14,B11,B12,B13,ZZ,DD

I need a regular expression for

1. If I find A01,A02,A03 or A11,A12,A13,A14 in my line, I have to replace with "AA"
2. If I find B11,B12,B13 I have to replace with "BB"

I have tried using

```
if (Regex.IsMatch(Value, "^A0[2-9]")|| Regex.IsMatch(Value, "^A1[0-5]"))
```

It didnt work  -- so basically if i have A02,A03, A04, A05, A06, A07 or A10,A11,A12....... A15 , I have to replace with "AA"

Comment: From your given input string `XX,VV,A01,A02,A03,A11,A12,A13,A14,B11,B12,B13,ZZ,DD`, what does your desired output string need to look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Description

```regex
(?:((?:[AB](?=0[2-9]|1[0-5])))[0-9]{2}(?:(?=,\s*\1),|))*
```

**Replace With:** `$1$1`

[image: Regular expression visualization]

This regular expression will do the following:

- finds consecutive comma delimited runs of `A02` - `A15` or `B02` - `B15`
- replaces the entire run with either `AA` or `BB`

## Example

**Live Demo**

https://regex101.com/r/gN8aP6/1

**Sample text**

```
XX,VV,A01,A02,A03,A11,A12,A13,A14,B11,B12,B13,ZZ,DD
```

**Sample Matches**

```
XX,VV,A01,AA,BB,ZZ,DD
```

## Explanation

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    (                        group and capture to \1:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      (?:                      group, but do not capture:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
        [AB]                     any character of: 'A', 'B'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
        (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
          0                        '0'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
          [2-9]                    any character of: '2' to '9'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
         |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
          1                        '1'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
          [0-5]                    any character of: '0' to '5'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
        )                        end of look-ahead
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      )                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of \1
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [0-9]{2}                 any character of: '0' to '9' (2 times)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
        ,                        ','
----------------------------------------------------------------------
        \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
                                 (0 or more times (matching the most
                                 amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
        \1                       what was matched by capture \1
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      )                        end of look-ahead
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      ,                        ','
----------------------------------------------------------------------
     |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )*                       end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Hi Thanyou for the response. Could you please give a regex just for replacing the A's and not B's  

XX,VV,A02,A03,A11,A12,A13,A14,ZZ,DD
replace with XX,VV,AA,ZZ,DD
For some of them , it says Unrecognized escape sequence.


Thanks

Comment: @Kathy with your given string `XX,VV,A01,A02,A03,A11,A12,A13,A14,ZZ,DD` what does the desired string look like?

Comment: I want this XX,VV,AA,ZZ,DD from XX,VV,A02,A03,A11,A12,A13,A14,ZZ,DD

Comment: I am so new to regex. Please help!

Comment: So your over all question is a bit confusing, but `(?:(((?:[AB](?=[0-9]{2}))))[0-9]{2}(?:(?=,\s*\2),|))*` this regex will convert your example string to `XX,VV,AA,ZZ,DD`. Of course if you're input string also contains `B01,B02...` then it'll also replace those. To limit this behavior you can simply change the letters in `[AB]` portion to be the letters you'd like matched.  See also [working demo](https://regex101.com/r/aK4cS1/2)

Comment: This is not working fr some reason...If i have A01 ----- A05 or A10 ---- A15 it should not convert to AA. This is what i want exactly. Please disregard B in the regex

Yes I have changed [AB] to just [A] and at ,\s*\2) It says unrecognized escape sequence

Comment: So if you have `XX,VV,A01,A02,A03,A04,A05,A06,A07,A08,A09,A10,A11,A12,A13,A14,A15,A16,A17,A18,A19,A20,ZZ,DD` it should look like `XX,VV,AA,ZZ,DD`?

Comment: I am not able to chat, this is my first post. Yes, But it moght not be that I have all from A02 -A09 and A10-A15 in the line. So When I have A02-A09 or A10 - A15, I chnage it to AA. Thankyou!

Comment: Change in the requirement! Very Sorry and thankyou 
I am not able to chat, this is my first post. Yes, But it moght not be that I have all from A02 -A09 and A10-A15 in the line. So When I have A02-A09 or A10 - A15, I chnage it to ABC. Thankyou

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove the `^` from your expression like `A0[2-9]`. Since the result is not at the beginning of your expression(^).

**[Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qA7mK6/1)**

[.NET Fiddle Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/mT3VmQ)

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public static class Sample1
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var sampleInput = "XX,VV,A01,A02,A03,A11,A12,A13,A14,B11,B12,B13,ZZ,DD";
        var results = Regex.Replace(sampleInput, "A0[2-9]|A1[0-5]", "AA");
        Console.WriteLine("Line: {0}", results);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thankyou very much for the response. But this is replacing the whole sampleInput into AA and leaving the others out. I do not want it that way, It should only replace the A's and keep the others as it is.